# Identify UIViews for holding information

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, hash

I would like to keep track of my `UIView's` (and subclasses of `UIViews`), in this case, their frames. I would like to keep a ponter indicating each subview of mine in a `NSDictionary` with their related frame.

I implemented something like this;

```
    NSMutableDictionary *subviewRects = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

    // iterate through all subviews ans save their CGRects
    for (UIView *subview in self.holder.subviews) {
        NSValue *rectValue = [NSValue valueWithCGRect:subview.frame];
        [subviewRects setObject:rectValue forKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",subview.hash]];
    }
```

But I am not sure if this is the right way to achieve this, or even more important, will `hash` property of `UIView` change during the lifecycle of related `UIViewController`?

**Note:** I forgot to tell that I cannot use `tag` property of `UIView` in this situation.

Comment: You can use view's tag property for identifying views but I think this is hard work to do if you have lots of views and a complex view hierarchy. Just from curiosity, why would you try to do something like this ?

Comment: I have a design where autosizing cannot arrange my subviews when a rotation occurs. I will force input my cgrects, so I am trying to lower my workforce as much as I can, and yeah I added that I cannot use tag to the note :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most inheritors of UIView that I know of will have a static hash value. However, beware: this isn't guaranteed to be true, because subclasses can override hash.

Instead, it might be better to keep track of your views either through a simple naming scheme or simply use object pointers to hold the reference instead (use %p instead of %@ to get just an object's pointer instead of a description).

As an aside: do note you're using the hash value of the controller's view object to store each rect of the subview. Are you sure you don't mean to use the hash value of each subview?

Comment: storing the pointer is what I wanted in the first place! How can I get a NSObject's pointer, can you show a simple code? And yes, I just prepd that code to ask my question, fixed that part as well, nice catch :)

Comment: @Bartu Your subview instance is a pointer : [subviewRects setObject:rectValue forKey:[NSValue  valueWithPointer:subview]]; but why not simply using your subview as key ? [subviewRects setObject:rectValue forKey:subview];